# Simple expression in sql-stored component

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to reference the property value "**myproperty**" using a simple expression in the sql-stored component, but I get an error saying that Camel was expecting a SIMPLE_EXP_TOKEN

Is this unsupported using sql-stored?

```
SUBNUMBERS(
  INTEGER ${properties:myproperty},
  INTEGER ${headers.num2},
  OUT INTEGER resultofsub
)
```

Comment: Try put ${properties:myproperty} to some header and then use that header in the sql-stored expression. There is a pull request https://github.com/apache/camel/pull/1673 that should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Ah its because you use colon `:` in the simple expression which is not supported in the grammar:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-sql/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/sql/stored/template/grammar/sspt.jj#L145

You are welcome to log a JIRA and to try to provide a patch to include the colon, and an unit test is also appreciated
http://camel.apache.org/support.html
http://camel.apache.org/contributing.html

A github PR is the easiest
https://github.com/apache/camel/